# Using MATLAB linspace between every element in an array

Tags: matlab, linear-interpolation

Using MATLAB, I would like to linearly interpolate between every point in an array.

Using `interpolate` will do it in a non-linear fashion.  What I want to do is similar to producing low-pass filter coefficients.

I have come up with a solution, but I would like to avoid using `for` loops:

```
a=[0 0 1 0 0]; %Input matrix
N=5; %Number of points to be added
b=[];
for i=1:length(a)-1
    b=[b linspace(a(i),a(i+1),N)];
end
```

Is it possible to do this without a loop?

Comment: The interpolation method is an input into `interp1`. You could use `interp1(x,v,xq,'linear')` Where x is your sampling locations, v is your data and xq is your desired sample locations. See the [help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a **linear spline** with the points in `a` as control points.  After that you can specify as many points as you want from a beginning interval to an ending interval.  As what Raab70 said, you can use `interp1`.  `interp1` can be called in the following way (using `linear` interpolation):

```
out = interp1(x, y, xp, 'linear')
```

`x` are the `x` values and `y` are the `y` values for the control points.  `xp` are the points you want to evaluate the function at.  Because you don't explicitly have `x` values and you just want the `y` values, you can create a dummy vector that goes from 1 up to `L` where `L` is how many points are in your output data.  This dummy vector is for your `x` values.  After, specify `y` as your output data.  In this case, it is the array of `a`.  Next, you need to specify where you want to sample along the curve.  Because you want to introduce 5 points in between each space, you will have in total 5*4 + 5 = 25 points all together.  5 points per "slot", and there are 4 slots all together.  You also include the 5 points that were from your original output data.  To create these 25 points, simply perform `linspace` from 1 up to 5 and specify that you want 25 points in between this interval.  This should perfectly capture the control points (the dummy values of `1,2,3,4,5`) as well as the values that you want to use to interpolate in between each of the control points.

As such, try something like this:

```
N = 5; %// Number of points to introduce in between each control point
y = [0 0 1 0 0]; %// Your output data
L = numel(y); %// Size of output data. Cache so we don't have to keep typing in numel(y)
x = 1:L; %// Dummy vector
xp = linspace(1, L, N*(L-1) + N); %// Create points to interpolate. N*(L-1) + N is also just N*L
out = interp1(x, y, xp, 'linear'); %// Generate interpolated array
```

`out` thus gives me:

```
out =

Columns 1 through 9

     0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.1667    0.3333

Columns 10 through 18

0.5000    0.6667    0.8333    1.0000    0.8333    0.6667    0.5000    0.3333    0.1667

Columns 19 through 25

     0         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

Comment: Great.  I made a simple red-white-green colormap with cmap_rwg=interp1((0:2)/2,[1,0,0;1,1,1;0,1,0],(1:100)/100);