# Interpolate 1D array with n points

Tags: matlab, performance

I have a large sorted 1D array of unevenly spaced floats which I would like to interpolate with `n` points. What is the fastest and neatest way to do this?

e.g. consider  an array

```
A = [1,1.5,2,3,5];
```

Which I would like to interpolate such that I obtain

```
B = [1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2,2.5,3,4,5];
```

One way to obtain this is through a for loop and `linspace`, e.i.:

```
n = 3;
B = zeros((n-1)*length(A)-1,1);
for i = 1:length(A)-1
    B((n-1)*(i-1)+1:(n-1)*i+1) = linspace(A(i),A(i+1),n);
end
```

But I think this way seems too tedious compared to the difficulty of the problem, and like there should be a one-liner for it. Also such that I do not recalculate the endpoints at every loop.

Comment: This was the first hit when I googled your question title. Perhaps it will help. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html

Comment: I have scrutinised that page several times, but that function interpolates a 1D function, e.i. you have both x, and y data, at specific points. I am interested in uniformly expanding an array. So it does unfortunately not work, even though the headlines are almost alike.

Comment: This also may be a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525001/using-matlab-linspace-between-every-element-in-an-array/.  I think this one is more in line with what you're looking for.  The one I marked as duplicate is more generic.

Comment: I might be missing something, but running the code suggested in your link on `y=A` from my example above, and `n=2` does not produce the wanted result.

Comment: The duplicate question(s) provide solution(s) but in this case where you want `m` additional equally spaced points between each point in `A` then `B = interp1(A,1:1/(m+1):length(A))` will do the job quite neatly.

Comment: Of course, now the solution also makes sense for me.

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar The second duplicate I posted does that.  I should have flagged with that one instead.